# Spotfire: Can you write a case statement based on a column containing a substring

Tags: filter, dashboard, spotfire, substring

I want to create a calculated column based on a substring. I can't find the syntax to do something like the following

```
 case 
 when [ProjectName] contains "substring" then [Value]
 end
```

For example, when the [ProjectName] contains "overhead" then "overhead"
[ProjectName] would be equal to "Project 1 Overhead", "Project 2 billable", or something like that.

Comment: Doable for sure and great question. I'll answer tomorrow if no one else has.

Comment: I thought you would be able to do it with *string* or $csearch. Not sure why they don't work.

Comment: Sorry i totally forgot about this--glad you posted a comment to remember me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use `FIND()` with an `IF()` or `CASE()` statement.

```
If(Find("overhead",Lower([ProjectName])) >0,[Value],"FALSE")

CASE 
    WHEN Find("overhead",Lower([ProjectName])) >0 THEN [Value]
END
```

Just remember, `Find()` is case sensitive.

If this is a step in replacing the sub-string with a value, then you would want to use `RXReplace()`